# W3C HTML validator webpage won't load

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have NO idea what the problem is. I need to validate my website as part of a uni assignment on w3.org and for some reason, this page just will not load. The CSS and HTML validator pages won't load at all, it says "network timed out". I have no clue why this is, it's been like this since I can remember. I have reset safari, emptied the cache, tried it on 3 computers in my house all in different browsers.

Any ideas what the problem may be? It worked once tonight when I went to w3.org and clicked the HTML validator link, after I validated the page once it never worked again!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Which page is not loading? The validator itself or your page within the validator?

Comment: Could you provide links to the actual pages that you are trying to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing worth noting is that your university probably has their own HTML mark up validation, it'll be on the DCS network somewhere. If no luck with W3C then use your university's one.